# Node weird stack trace

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, stack-trace

If I execute the following code :

```
"use strict";

const config = {};
const run = (fn, params) => fn(params);

run(
    params => {
        throw new Error("Simple test!");
    },
    { config }
);
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
Error: Simple test!
    at run.config.config (C:\test\test.js:10:9)
    at run (C:\test\test.js:6:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\test\test.js:8:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

Is it normal to have `run.config.config` or is it a bug?

Comment: This looks weird indeed. Node seems to derive a name for the anonymous callback you pass into `run`, no idea how it arrives at `config` for that.

Comment: I suppose `{ config }` creates a new `config` property within the original `config`

Comment: I can reproduce this in Chrome devtools console, so it's probably a V8 thing

Comment: @KooiInc No, that's just an object literal with a single property holding the `config` object. The `config` object is not modified. And anyway, this doesn't answer why the `config` object appears in the stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{config}` creates an object with property `config` from the original `config`.

The stack seems to be: `config` from parameter `{config}`. So "`run.{config}.config`" from `run`, apparently displayed as `run.config.config`.

The stack trace is different if `fn` is assigned earlier (so, when `fn` is *not anonymous*).

```js
const config = {foo: 1, bar: 2};
const run = (fn, config) => {
  fn(config);
};

const runFn = params => { 
    console.log(`current params: ${JSON.stringify(params)}`); 
    throw new Error("Caught ya'");
}

run(runFn, {config});
```

Nodejs output with **fn parameter as predefined named function** (above snippet):

```
current params: {"config":{"foo":1,"bar":2}}
[...]\SO65523965.js:8
    throw new Error("Caught ya'");
    ^

Error: Caught ya'
    at runFn ([...]\SO65523965.js:8:11)
    at run ([...]\SO65523965.js:3:3)
    ...
```

Nodejs output with **inline fn parameter**:

```
current params: {"config":{"foo":1,"bar":2}}
[...]\SO65523965.js:8
    throw new Error("Caught ya'");
    ^

Error: Caught ya'
    at run.config.config ([...]\SO65523965.js:13:11)
    at run ([...]\SO65523965.js:3:3)
```

Comment: Not the DV, but not sure this actually answers the question.

Comment: But what does the call to `fn` have to do with the config argument?

Comment: Not sure, but see the edited answer. The 'strange' error only shows when `fn` is inlined, so when `fn` is *anonymous*. In that case I suppose `fn`'s parent name is taken and some strange guessing from the v8 interpreter is going on.

Comment: [See also](https://v8.dev/docs/stack-trace-api#appendix%3A-stack-trace-format)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it normal to have run.config.config or is it a bug?

if you are pointing out that the `config` object shouldn't be mentioned in the stack trace since it's not related to the error, the yeah that's weird, in the other hand if you are wondering about the `config.config`, then i suspect that:

thanks to the [Shorthand property names syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)
this:

```js
const a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
const obj = {a, b, c};
```

is equivalent to this:

```js
const a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
const obj = {a:a, b:b, c:c};
```

---

in the same way that, this:

```js
run(params => {
        throw new Error("Simple test!");
    },
    { config }
);
```

is equivalent to:

```js
run(params => {
        throw new Error("Simple test!");
    },
    { config: config }
);
```

which could explain the `config.config` part, the first `config` seem to refer to the object `{ config: config }` and the second (`.config`) refer to the `config` property name of the mentioned object

Comment: If you try the code with `{ config: config }` though, you'll get only `run.config` in the stack trace.